# tKinter fullscreen moves window on my secondary display 5 pixels

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, fullscreen, ubuntu-22.04

Just implemented a fullscreen option on my tKinter python app.
Works fine bust some unexpected behaviour.

My laptop is connected to a secondary screen.
When switching my app to fullscreen mode, the window on my secondary display moves 5 pixels. When I escape fullscreen mode, the window in my secondary screen moves back to the original position.

Anyone else experienced this behaviour?

Thank you for responding. I use a function:

```
def switch_FullScreen(*args):
    root.attributes("-fullscreen", 1)
    return true
```

[python3.10]

Comment: How do you implement the fullscreen option exactly?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with `.attributes("-fullscreen", <bool>)` (archlinux, XFCE, python3.10)

Comment: I have put the function in the question.